# How to covert data type of mobus data array into REAL datatype

Tags: php, modbus

I am working on mod-bus registers. I am new to this field so i am facing some of the issues.
I have get the data in an array from the mod-bus and it is displaying my values into int but i want the data in real data type. 
Waiting for your kind response.
P.S: kindly ignore my mistakes

```
// for automatically refreshing the page every one second
header('Refresh: 1'); 
//setting the time zone and getting the date and time
$timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')){
   date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
}
echo date('d-m-Y'). "</br>";
echo date('H:i:s'). "</br>";
//reference to ModbusMaster.php file where the modbus php protocol is defined
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpmodbus/Phpmodbus/ModbusMaster.php';
// Create Modbus object
$modbus = new ModbusMaster("192.168.1.49", "TCP");

//Energy Meter
// FC3 = Function Code 3 to read holding registers
/*Setting device ID = 5, Starting address as 100 and 
  number of registers to be read as 120
*/
try {
    // FC 3
    $recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(2, 4000, 6);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Print error information if any
    echo $modbus;
    echo $e;
    exit;
}

// Print status information
echo "</br>Status:</br>" . $modbus;

// Conversion
echo "<h2>EN8400</h2>\n";
print_r($recData);

// Chunk the data array to set of 4 bytes
$values = array_chunk($recData, 4);
print_r($values);
$energymeter_param = array();
$count = 1;
foreach($values as $bytes){   
      $temp = PhpType::bytes2unsignedint($bytes);
      $energymeter_param[$count] = $temp;

    $count++;
}
//Store the number of energy meter parameters in a variable
$num_energymeter_param = $count;
echo "<h3>Energy meter array</h3>\n";
//print array 
print_r ($energymeter_param)." </br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your data is represented. In Modbus you need two registers to store a float. Then you need to check on the manual of your device the [endianness](https://store.chipkin.com/articles/how-real-floating-point-and-32-bit-data-is-encoded-in-modbus-rtu-messages) of these registers and the order of the bits within.

If you read registers two at a time then you can use the helper function provided with *phpModbus*:

```
PhpType::bytes2float($recData, $endianness)
```

Or:

```
PhpType::bytes2float(array_reverse($recData), $endianness)
```

Where `$endianness` can be 0 or 1.

**EDIT:** Knowing your [device](https://www.schneider-electric.com/library/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/SE_LOCAL/APS/206811_1E96/PM750_Public_Register_List_v3.150.pdf) and that you are trying to read a `long` type the format is Unsigned 32-bit integer Upper 16-bits (MSW) in lowest-numbered register (4001/4000 = MSW/LSW) so you cannot use the`bytes2float()` function at all.

You were on the right path with `PhpType::bytes2unsignedint($bytes)` but it seems you have to change the default endianness:

```
PhpType::bytes2unsignedint($bytes, 1)
```

Apologies for the confusion, I was assuming you were reading a float.

Comment: Have you read registers two at a time? Maybe you can post what results you got and the brand and model of your device to double-check its format

Comment: I have just used the $recData array in the above statement you have written. I am new to this so i am facing these troubles. Actually i need the data in 32 bit. Because i am dealing with KWh. Some values i need in 16 bit for that above code is working fine but i am not able to resolve it for 32 bit.

Comment: You can only use the `bytes2float()`directly if you are reading ***two registers***. In your code you're reading 6 registers so you either read only two or you split them with `chunk`. If you tell me what energy meter you're using I can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: I am working on Schneider Electric energy meter. $values = array_chunk($recData, 2); i have used this and after that converted into float the results are like that:
Energy meter array
Array ( [1] => 5.651436706622E-42 [2] => 5.7817574638042E-42 [3] => 5.8097834330907E-42 [4] => 3.2622228249482E-42 [5] => 3.2720319141984E-42 [6] => 3.4233721483455E-42 )

Comment: That means you're not using the correct format. Have you tried changing the endianness and/or using `array_reverse?

Comment: You need to double check the data type on your Modbus map. Do you have a spreadsheet for that? Otherwise, look for your device [here](https://www.ccontrols.com/support/dp/ION_Meter_Modbus.pdf) and try to find the register number you're trying to get. These documents should tell you if you need to read more registers (if the variables are FLOAT32 you need to read 2 registers but if they are FLOAT64 you need to read 4). I can help you double check but you'd need to give me the device model.

Comment: Register :4000 Name:Real Energy, Consumption Size: 2 Type: Long Model: PM750

Comment: According to [this](https://www.schneider-electric.com/library/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/SE_LOCAL/APS/206811_1E96/PM750_Public_Register_List_v3.150.pdf) for a `long` type the format is Unsigned 32-bit integer Upper 16-bits (MSW) in lowest-numbered register (4001/4000 = MSW/LSW) so you cannot use the`bytes2float()` function at all. Let me edit my answer

Comment: Yes please i will be highly thankful to you for your help.

Comment: Great. Good luck with your metering!

Comment: Marcos G i need some help from you

Comment: I'm listening, it it's long to explain you can post a question and I'll take a look

Comment: I have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160576/how-to-get-64-bit-data-from-modbus-registers