# How to get 64 Bit data from Modbus Registers

Tags: php

I have worked on metering the modbus data and i did it for 16 bit and 32 bit data. but now i have a requirement of 64 bit data.

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/phpmodbus/Phpmodbus/ModbusMaster.php';
$modbus = new ModbusMaster("192.168.1.49", "TCP");
//KWh
try {
$recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(2, 3999, 6);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo $modbus;
echo $e;
exit;
}
$values = array_chunk($recData, 4);
?>
```

for *16 bit i write as `$values = array_chunk($recData, 2);`*

for *32 bit i write as `$values = array_chunk($recData, 4);`*

but *for 64 bit when i write `$values = array_chunk($recData, 8);`* it gives error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: The input data should be an array of
>   2 or 4 bytes. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Kohat_Cement\Phpmodbus\PhpType.php:207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with your data types.

First thing to consider is that **one** Modbus register stores 16 bit.

So two registers should be 32 bit and 4 registers 64 bit.

With that in mind, you need to review the manual of your device and see the width of each data word, which is the number of registers you need to read.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196921/discussion-on-answer-by-marcos-g-how-to-get-64-bit-data-from-modbus-registers).